# refactoring code in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

```
if (!$this->getUser()->isAuthenticated())
{
  $this->redirect('login/index');
}
```

i would like add this code for many actions in different modules. I must copy this code for each action? I would like make somethings:

```
//module 

class Invite
public function executeIndex {
 sfConfig:get('redirect');
}


class Home
public function executeIndex {
 sfConfig:get('redirect');
}

public function executeShow {
  sfConfig:get('redirect');
}
```

if  can't be in different modules, although it might in a single?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a filter. [See here](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_filters)

Answer (score 1):

You can use symfony's built-in security filter.

If your want to secure the whole module, create the apps/app/modules/module/config/security.yml with the following content:

```
all:
  is_secure: true
```

If you only want the show action to be secure:

```
show:
  is_secure: true
```

Note that you only need the name of the action, not including the result (eg. Success).

You can do a lot with only the builtin security layer, even more with something like sf(Doctrine)GuardPlugin. For more information, see [Gentle introduction to symfony, chapter 6, action security](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_action_security).